# Sum the result of a SELECT that returns several rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

i am trying to sum the result of a select that return several rows:
i have four tables (user, team, pilot, result):

```
user (id_user)
team (id_user, id_team)
pilot (id_pilot, id_team)
result (id_pilot, id_gp, points)
```

When i do that:

```
SELECT p.id_team, SUM( r.points ) AS TOTAL
FROM pilot p
LEFT JOIN result r ON p.id_pilot = r.id_pilot
WHERE r.id_grand_prix =  '1'
GROUP BY p.id_team
```

i get:

```
id_team TOTAL
-------------
1 10
2 15
3 5
4 6
5 7
```

what i want is, if id_user has id_team 1 and 2 has 25 points.

i try that:

```
UPDATE user AS u 
JOIN has_team ON u.id_user = has_team.id_user 
JOIN (
    SELECT p.id_team, SUM( r.position ) AS TOTAL
    FROM pilot p
    LEFT JOIN result r ON p.id_pilot = r.id_pilot
    WHERE r.id_grand_prix =  '1'
    GROUP BY p.id_team
    ) AS grp 
  ON grp.id_team = has_team.id_team
SET u.points = grp.TOTAL + u.points
```

but i only have the points of one team.

thanx very much in advance how can help me.

Comment: Your sample has new table `has_team` and isnt describe in your schema. Also you have `id_grand_prix` and `id_gp`. Finally isnt clear what you want.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: is there any relationship between `pilot` and `user`?

Comment: Firstly thank u for your quickly answer. I am very new, sorry. Thats right, has_team is team table, and id_gp is id_grand_prix. What i want is to update a field in user table called points, and that user points is the sum of the points get the teams he has. Hope is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to get the SUM of points for each user, instead of each team?

If so, your query might be something like this:

```
SELECT u.id_user, SUM( r.points ) AS TOTAL
FROM pilot p
LEFT JOIN result r ON p.id_pilot = r.id_pilot
INNER JOIN team t ON p.id_team = t.id_team
INNER JOIN user u ON t.id_user = u.id_user
WHERE r.id_grand_prix =  '1'
GROUP BY u.id_user
```

If not, could you clarify what you need to display?

Comment: Perfect! Thats the solution. Works me fine! Thank u very much completeitpro! Respect.